# Exercice 8, p.922 from Stewart's Calculus: Concepts and Contexts

Tags: integration

I try to do this exercice: $\int_C \sin x\, dx + \cos y\, dy$, where $C$ consists of the top half circle $x^2+y^2=1$ from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$ and the line segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(2,3)$.

I'm fine with the segment, but over the circle my fist guess was to use polar coodrinates, but I got something ugly... very ugly...

Unfornatly, time is running out, exam tomorow... so if you guys can give me the steps it will help me

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With polar coordinates: $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, so that $dx=-\sin tdt$, $dy=\cos tdt$ and the integral become:
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(\cos t)(-\sin t) dt+\int_0^\pi \cos(\sin t)\cos t dt=-\cos(\cos t)+\sin(\sin t)|_0^\pi=0$$.

Comment: hmm... that was I tried to do, but I didn't realize I can use $u=cos(t) \ du=-sin(t)dt$ and was stuck a while trying to solve $\int \sin(\cos(t))dt$... thk you!

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be seen as
$$I=\int_C \sin x\, dx + \cos y\, dy=\int_C\overrightarrow{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\overrightarrow{r}$$
where $\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)=(\sin x,\cos y)$. As $\frac{\partial {F_x}}{\partial {y}}-\frac{\partial {F_y}}{\partial {x}}=0$, there exists $V(x,y)$, such that $\nabla V(x,y)=\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)$, for example, $V(x,y)=-\cos x+\sin y$. The integral can than be calculated as
$$I=\int_C\nabla V\cdot\mathrm{d}\overrightarrow{r}=V(b)-V(a)$$
where $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(2,3)$ are the initial and final points of $C$. So
$$I=V(2,3)-V(1,0)=-\cos 2+\sin 3+\cos 1$$